# Using Rest Api how to load data in dropdown in Vuejs?

Tags: javascript, vue.js, drop-down-menu, axios

```js
new Vue({
    el: '#app',
    
    data: function() {
        return {
            countries: [],
            cities: [],
            selectedContinent: "",
            selectedCountry: "",
            selectedCity: ""
        }
    },
    watch: {
        selectedContinent: function() {
            // Clear previously selected values
            this.countries = [];
            this.cities = [];
            this.selectedCountry = "";
            this.selectedCity = "";
            // Populate list of countries in the second dropdown
            if (this.selectedContinent.length > 0) {
                this.countries = this.places[this.selectedContinent]
            }
        },
        selectedCountry: function() {
            // Clear previously selected values
            this.cities = [];
            this.selectedCity = "";
            // Now we have a continent and country. Populate list of cities in the third dropdown
            if (this.selectedCountry.length > 0) {
                this.cities = this.places[this.selectedContinent][this.selectedCountry]
            }
        }
    }
})
```

```css
.dropdown {
    margin: 10px 0;
    padding: 10px 0;
    border-bottom: 1px solid #DDD;
}

.dropdown span {
    display:inline-block;
    width: 80px;
}
```

```html
<body>
    <div id="app">
       <div class="cascading-dropdown">
            <div class="dropdown">
                <span>Continent:</span>
                <select v-model="selectedContinent">
                    <option value="">Select a Continent</option>
                    <option v-for="(country_obj, country) in places" :value="country">{{country}}</option>
                </select>
            </div>
            <div class="dropdown">
                <span>Country:</span>
                <select :disabled="countries.length == 0" v-model="selectedCountry">
                    <option value="">Select a Country</option>
                    <option v-for="(city_obj, city) in countries">{{city}}</option>
                </select>
            </div>
            <div class="dropdown"> 
                <span>City:</span>
                <select :disabled="cities.length == 0" v-model="selectedCity">
                    <option value="">Select a City</option>
                    <option v-for="city in cities">{{city}}</option>
                </select>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div> 
</body>
```

Below is the REST API for countries, states and cities
https://www.universal-tutorial.com/rest-apis/free-rest-api-for-country-state-city
and I have generated a token.
Generated Token : IIPwMXygilaKrQJfNLuj-LHZWn5kxBVZRLJ-KtU5jxRivdTBkHio6IOyF60CERyOPjo

Working codesandbox link:-
https://jsfiddle.net/Dhanunjay/sj24kn0b/6/

With the list of items in data, i am able to load data in dropdown. But i am not sure how to load data using rest api in dropdown

Followed this documentation for Free REST API for countries, states and cities

Comment: It depends a bit how you want to use it. If you want to show data from the API response in the dropdown then you should make the api call in the mounted lifecycle hook and assign the response.data to a predefined item in data and loop through it in the template. You probably need to format the response though.

If you want to show the data on each dropdown change then turn it into a function and call it each time a new item gets selected.

Comment: @uke5tar I tried the below code https://jsfiddle.net/Dhanunjay/sj24kn0b/5/
I looped data in the template. But i am not sure how to assign the response to the dropdown.

Can you please help me on how to place response in dropdown.

Comment: @uke5tar I updated my code as you said. But response how to load in dropdown not aware.

Comment: Do you mean like this: https://codesandbox.io/s/dropdown-city-state-country-axios-call-vue-forked-5svl9?file=/src/App.vue ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

***Step 1:*** Create `HTML` your template

```
<template>
  <div class="cascading-dropdown">
    <div class="dropdown">
      <H2>Build a reusable dropdown vue component</H2>
      <span>Country:</span>
      <select v-model="selectedCountry" @change="onChangeCountry">
        <option value="">Select a Country</option>
        <option
          v-for="(country, index) in listCountry"
          :value="country.country_name"
          :key="index"
        >
          {{ country.country_name }}
        </option>
      </select>
    </div>
    <div class="dropdown">
      <span>State:</span>
      <select
        :disabled="listState.length == 0"
        v-model="selectedState"
        @change="onChangeState"
      >
        <option value="">Select a State</option>
        <option
          v-for="(state, index) in listState"
          :key="index"
          :value="state.state_name"
        >
          {{ state.state_name }}
        </option>
      </select>
    </div>
    <div class="dropdown">
      <span>State:</span>
      <select :disabled="listCities.length == 0" v-model="selectedCity">
        <option value="">Select a City</option>
        <option
          v-for="(city, index) in listCities"
          :key="index"
          :value="city.city_name"
        >
          {{ city.city_name }}
        </option>
      </select>
    </div>
    <p v-if="selectedCountry">Selected Country - {{ this.selectedCountry }}</p>
    <p v-if="selectedState">Selected State - {{ this.selectedState }}</p>
    <p v-if="selectedCity">Selected City - {{ this.selectedCity }}</p>
  </div>
</template>
```

***Step 2:*** Create `model` data

```
data() {
  return {
    listCountry: [],
    listState: [],
    listCities: [],
    selectedCountry: "",
    selectedState: "",
    selectedCity: "",
    authToken: "",
  };
},
```

***Step 3:*** For getting Free REST API for countries, states and cities. We needs to generate `auth_token` from `api-token`

```
generateAccessToken() {
  axios
    .get("https://www.universal-tutorial.com/api/getaccesstoken", {
      headers: {
        Accept: "application/json",
        "api-token":
          "jAJuES2nNREYu0qOJ9Sy6bydr_LPxmjv0jUAR-oEuXozRP_CjqPqRgp1mCPaNh8VPZo",
        "user-email": "itjebasuthan@gmail.com",
      },
    })
    .then((res) => {
      this.authToken = res.data.auth_token;
      this.loadCountry();
    });
},
```

***Step 4:*** Create `onChange` events for country, state and cities

```
loadCountry() {
  axios
    .get("https://www.universal-tutorial.com/api/countries", {
      headers: {
        Authorization: `Bearer ${this.authToken}`,
        Accept: "application/json",
      },
    })
    .then((res) => {
      this.listCountry = res.data;
    });
},
onChangeCountry() {
  axios
    .get(
      `https://www.universal-tutorial.com/api/states/${this.selectedCountry}`,
      {
        headers: {
          Authorization: `Bearer ${this.authToken}`,
          Accept: "application/json",
        },
      }
    )
    .then((res) => {
      this.listState = res.data;
    });
},
onChangeState() {
  axios
    .get(
      `https://www.universal-tutorial.com/api/cities/${this.selectedState}`,
      {
        headers: {
          Authorization: `Bearer ${this.authToken}`,
          Accept: "application/json",
        },
      }
    )
    .then((res) => {
      this.listCities = res.data;
    });
},
```

[DEMO](https://codesandbox.io/s/beautiful-turing-npj1t)